# Passing QSqlQueryModel through control class

Tags: c++, qt, data-binding, data-modeling, qtsql

How would I go about passing `QSqlQueryModel` from a class that connects and queries the database through the control class or [QMainWindow in my attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14708/passing-data-with-qts-qsqlquerymodel) and back to the widget needing the information?

I thought I could pass the reference location to the `QSqlQueryModel` object, but this is not working or [I am doing something wrong](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14708/passing-data-with-qts-qsqlquerymodel).

I haven't found any examples showing what I am doing on the [Qt Developer page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-sql.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like these are just compiler errors, nothing specifically to do with Qt.

In short you are getting your pointers and references mixed up.

**Error #1:**

`cardList = new List(sqlModel->getListModel());`

You are passing a reference when the `List` takes a pointer. Fix your return type from `getListModel` or fix the above line.

Next, you are not specifying  the second argument, i.e. the parent `QWidget`. Either specify your `MainWindow` as the parent, pass `0`, or fix your constructor's signature to provide a default (generally `0`).

**Error #2:**

```
List::List(QSqlQueryModel *model, QWidget *parent) :  ListUI(parent){
    setListItems(&model);
}
```

You receive the `model` as a pointer and then attempted to take the address of the pointer. I.e. You're making a double pointer. Change the line to

```
setListItems(model);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: got it thanks!  I am glad I ran into this error and asked for assistance.  I really need to practice basic skills again, been awhile.